# "Files" not responding after 22.10->23.04 upgrade

Tags: nautilus, 23.04

Yesterday I installed the x86_64 Ubuntu 22.10 to a brand new, clean drive.  After it finished, I added Visual Studio Code, htop, mc and copied some source code and projects into my home directory.

This morning, I was warned that support for 22.10 would be ending soon and urged to upgrade to 23.04, so I did.  (Using the GUI upgrade interface.)

After the upgrade finished and the system rebooted, everything seems to work great -- EXCEPT for "files" (nautilus?) Any time I try to open that I see a message that "files has stopped responding" and an offer to close it or wait.  Waiting doesn't help because the same message reappears shortly after clicking wait.

I'm not an expert on linux and even less on a linux graphical desktop, so I have no idea what to do.

FWIW, I was able to get Visual Studio Code working, as well as Visual Slickedit (a 32 bit program!) and they don't seem to have a problem letting me browse for files to open.  That's probably not related, but I'm primarily a Windows programmer and almost all file open/save dialogs are actually part of the Windows File Explorer, so I thought that maybe nautilus provides that service as well.  Sorry if I'm stupid, just thinking out loud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try uninstalling and reinstalling "Files"

```
sudo apt pruge nemo && sudo apt purge nautilus && sudo apt install nemo nautilus
```

on Ubuntu there are two different applications that have the same name and icon "Files" (nemo and nautilus)

finally when you are browsing files with vscode or  Visual Slickedit you probably are using the default GNOME file chooser which is a seperate thing from nemo and nautilus so that's why they might be working.

Comment: Thanks, that sort of worked.  Nautilus will no longer even open a window, though the system shows it as running when launched.  However, nemo (which was not present before) appears to work perfectly.  So I checked the shortcut on the desktop from nautilus to nemo.  Thanks!